# How do I get ggplot to order facets correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to facet about 14 plots based on a variable that runs from 2-14. The plots show up in the order: 
10,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

How do I get them to order from 2-15?

update: ok, so I made it a factor using `data$var=as.factor(data$var)`. 
The Levels are 
`Levels: 10 11 12 13 14 15 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

How do I reorder those?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without your data, my best guess would be to turn your faceting variable into a factor that has the levels in the order which you desire.

Comment: ok, I figured out how to reorder levels. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: The code, if anyone is interested is: data$var=factor(data$var, levels(data$var)[c(7:14,1:5)])

Answer (score 22):

```
data$var <- factor(data$var, levels = sort(unique(data$var)))
```

Comment: and what's great is that you can also order facets in some predefined order. E.g. `f=c('Paul','Audrey','Marlene')`. Then simply say `d <- within(d, var <- factor(var, levels=f))`.

Comment: can you give an example, please? i don't understand what d is above...i am trying to facet weekdays but ordered by an int of day of week (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

Comment: for calycolor:  "d" above is the name of the data frame, called "data" in this example, so it would be, like "data <- within(data, var <- factor(var, levels =f)). ( If  you are ordering a grouped variable, you have to apply the new levels before doing the grouping.)  This facet ordering was hard for me to get, but this answer above is the one that helped.