# controlling order of facet_grid/facet_wrap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting things using `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` in ggplot, like:

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_histogram(aes(iris$Petal.Width)) + facet_grid(Species ~ .)
```

Is it possible to control the order in which the `Species` panels are ordered in the plot?  Can this be done without changing the `iris` dataframe or making a new one?  The default here shows setosa, versicolor, virginica but I'd like a different order. thanks.

Comment: maybe `facet_grid(factor(Species,levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor")) ~ .)` ? [oops, doesn't work]

Comment: As Ben notes, the way to control the ordering of basically everything in ggplot (bars in bar plots, facets, etc.) is to use a factor and adjust the order of the levels.

Comment: ...or this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3311901/324364

Comment: Jumping to duplicates is not helpful - Ben Bolker's answer is much simpler than the one given in the first post you link to. This is clearly a topic of interest and several approaches are useful.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I don't think I can really satisfy your "without making a new data frame" requirement, but you can create the new data frame on the fly:

```
ggplot(transform(iris,
      Species=factor(Species,levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor")))) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(Petal.Width))+ facet_grid(Species~.)
```

or, in tidyverse idiom:

```r
iris |>
   mutate(across(Species, ~factor(., levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor"))) |>
ggplot() + 
   geom_histogram(aes(Petal.Width))+ 
   facet_grid(Species~.)
```

I agree it would be nice if there were another way to control this, but `ggplot` is already a pretty powerful (and complicated) engine ...

Note that the order of (1) the **rows in the data set** is independent of the order of (2) the **levels of the factor**. #2 is what `factor(...,levels=...)` changes, and what `ggplot` looks at to determine the order of the facets.  Doing #1 (sorting the rows of the data frame in a specified order) is an interesting challenge. I think I would actually achieve this by doing #2 first, and then using `order()` or `arrange()` to sort according to the numeric values of the factor:

```
neworder <- c("virginica","setosa","versicolor")
library(plyr)  ## or dplyr (transform -> mutate)
iris2 <- arrange(transform(iris,
             Species=factor(Species,levels=neworder)),Species)
```

I can't immediately see a quick way to do this *without* changing the order of the factor levels (you could do it and then reset the order of the factor levels accordingly).

In general, functions in R that depend on the order of levels of a categorical variable are based on factor level order, not the order of the rows in the dataset: the answer above applies more generally.

Comment: Could you explain what the `transform` call is doing here precisely? If I type `transform(iris, factor(Species,levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor")))` into R, it doesn't output a dataframe with `Species` in the order given by `levels`

Comment: I think you left out the `Species=` part of the `transform` call ... `transform` *is* generating a new data frame.

Comment: I mistyped it, sorry. If I do `transform(iris, Species=factor(Species,levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor")))` in R, it outputs a dataframe that has the order: `setosa, versicolor, virginica` so I don't understand how transform works here. Your full call does produce the graph I wanted but I am confused as to why this `transform` call doesn't give the order specified in `levels`. thanks

Comment: the order of the **rows in the data set** is independent of the order of the **levels of the factor**.  The latter is what `ggplot` pays attention to.