# Reorder panels in facet_wrap/facet_grid based on another factor, with multiple occurrences

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

Consider this example. I want to create a custom label for my panels by joining two columns into a string.

The panels created through faceting are ordered alphabetically, but actually, I want them to be ordered by `src`, so SRC01 should come first, then SRC02, etc.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble::tibble(
  src = rep(c("SRC03", "SRC04", "SRC01", "SRC02"), 2),
  data = runif(8)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    foo = case_when(src %in% c("SRC01", "SRC02") ~ "foo", TRUE ~ "bar"),
    label = paste(foo, src)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = data)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~label)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I know that this order depends on the order of underlying factor levels, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116081/controlling-order-of-facet-grid-facet-wrap-in-ggplot2) shows how to manually specify the levels, which I do not want (there are many more `SRC` values and I don't want to type all of them…).

I found a solution using `fct_reorder`, in which I could specify:

```r
mutate(label = fct_reorder(label, src, .fun = identity))
```

But this only works when there is one line per `src/label` combination. If I add data (i.e., more than one data point per combination), it fails with:

```r
Error: `fun` must return a single value per group
```

What would be the most succinct way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the numeric part of `src`, and then use `reorder()`:

```
tibble::tibble(
  src = rep(c("SRC03", "SRC04", "SRC01", "SRC02"), 2),
  data = runif(8)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    foo = case_when(src %in% c("SRC01", "SRC02") ~ "foo", TRUE ~ "bar"),
    label = paste(foo, src)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(label_order = as.numeric(str_extract(src, "\\d+"))) %>% 
# use str_extract() to find the "01" inside "SRC01", turn it to numeric.
  ggplot(aes(x = data)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~reorder(label, label_order)) 
# user reorder to change the ordering based on the numbers
```

[image]

---

A note about `str_extract()`, it works on your example because:

`str_extract("SRC01", "\\d+")` gives `"01"`, then transformed to `1`. But:

`str_extract("2SRC01", "\\d+")` would return `2`, which wouldn't be ideal possibly.

Luckly there are tons of way to use regex to extract what you may need.

Comment: That works, thanks! Do you think though that a solution working with the natural alphanumeric order of `src` values is possible? Ideally I'd like to have `label` already be a factor that is correctly ordered and not resort to `reorder` in the plot.

Comment: `reorder` could be added inside `mutate`, like: `.. %>% mutate(label = reorder(label, label_order)) %>%.. `