# ggplot- multiple histograms, need them to be in a chronological order

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to display 16 individual histograms. I am able to create the unique histograms, but I want them to display in order of site elevation, from lowest elevation to highest.

[Temp by site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVKQE.png)

[Elevation data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTBBM.png)

```
library(ggplot2)
plt<-ggplot(data = snotel, aes(x = tavg)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 1.75) + 
 geom_density(alpha = 0.2, color = "red") +
 facet_wrap(~site)+
 geom_vline(xintercept=mean(snotel$tavg, na.rm=T), col = "blue", lwd = .5)

plt+labs(title = "Temperature per Site", x = "Temperature (C)",
       y = "Density")
```

I don't know how to sort the plots by a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the order of facet labels in ggplot (custom facet wrap labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490638/how-to-change-the-order-of-facet-labels-in-ggplot-custom-facet-wrap-labels) or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116081/controlling-order-of-facet-grid-facet-wrap-in-ggplot2